# AES key , decryptor = AES.new(HEADER_KEY, AES.MODE_CBC, 16 * '\x00')

Tags: python, python-3.x, encryption, cryptography, aes

Trying to run this code from 2017 - https://gist.github.com/dfirfpi/2602b726af1b944efa723d34b624ad88

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\unssz.py", line 58, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\unssz.py", line 34, in main
    decryptor = AES.new(HEADER_KEY, AES.MODE_CBC, 16 * '\x00')
  File "C:\Users\artur\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\Crypto\Cipher\AES.py", line 232, in new
    return _create_cipher(sys.modules[__name__], key, mode, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\artur\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\Crypto\Cipher\__init__.py", line 79, in _create_cipher
    return modes[mode](factory, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\artur\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\Crypto\Cipher\_mode_cbc.py", line 274, in _create_cbc_cipher
    cipher_state = factory._create_base_cipher(kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\artur\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\Crypto\Cipher\AES.py", line 103, in _create_base_cipher
    result = start_operation(c_uint8_ptr(key),
  File "C:\Users\artur\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\Crypto\Util\_raw_api.py", line 243, in c_uint8_ptr
    raise TypeError("Object type %s cannot be passed to C code" % type(data))
TypeError: Object type <class 'str'> cannot be passed to C code
```

Then changed line 34

```
decryptor = AES.new(HEADER_KEY, AES.MODE_CBC, 16 * '\x00')
```

to

```
decryptor = AES.new(HEADER_KEY.decode("utf8"), AES.MODE_CBC, 16 * '\x00')
```

got this error message

```
  File "C:\unssz.py", line 58, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\unssz.py", line 34, in main
    decryptor = AES.new(HEADER_KEY.encode("utf8"), AES.MODE_CBC, 16 * '\x00')
  File "C:\Users\artur\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\Crypto\Cipher\AES.py", line 232, in new
    return _create_cipher(sys.modules[__name__], key, mode, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\artur\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\Crypto\Cipher\__init__.py", line 79, in _create_cipher
    return modes[mode](factory, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\artur\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\Crypto\Cipher\_mode_cbc.py", line 274, in _create_cbc_cipher
    cipher_state = factory._create_base_cipher(kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\artur\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\Crypto\Cipher\AES.py", line 93, in _create_base_cipher
    raise ValueError("Incorrect AES key length (%d bytes)" % len(key))
ValueError: Incorrect AES key length (19 bytes)
```

what is wrong here, how to make it work? I'm trying Decrypt Samsung Secure Zone crypto container .msr file (forgot password)

```
from __future__ import print_function

from Crypto.Cipher import AES
import sys

CHUNK_SIZE = 4096
HEADER_SIZE = 16384
# AES key, for different crypto algorithms, different keys.
HEADER_KEY = '\x06\x42\x21\x98\x03\x69\x5E\xB1\x5F\x40\x60\x8C\x2E\x36\x00\x06'


def main():
    with open(sys.argv[1], 'rb') as input_file:
        header_enc = input_file.read(HEADER_SIZE)
        decryptor = AES.new(HEADER_KEY, AES.MODE_CBC, 16 * '\x00')
        header_dec = decryptor.decrypt(header_enc)

        body_decryption_key = header_dec[0x203c:0x204C]
        print('Decoding key: {}'.format(body_decryption_key.encode('hex')))

        if len(sys.argv) != 3:
            print('No output file specified, giving up...')
            sys.exit(0)

        decryptor = AES.new(body_decryption_key, AES.MODE_ECB, 16 * '\00')

        with open(sys.argv[2], 'wb') as output_file:
            while True:
                chunk_enc = input_file.read(CHUNK_SIZE)
                if len(chunk_enc) == 0:
                    break
                chunk_dec = decryptor.decrypt(chunk_enc)
                output_file.write(chunk_dec)
                sys.stdout.write('.')
                sys.stdout.flush()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: I'm not sure if this script actually works(will decrypt your data) but to you have to make sure to pass bytes and not strings to ```AES.new()``` so use ```HEADER_KEY = b'\x066....``` same as when setting The ```iv``` in calling ```AES.new``` use ```16 * b'\x00``` then you can try again

Comment: Hello, there are also similar code avilable https://github.com/kholia/SecretZone but not working , after adding b as you mentioned I have another issue  ' File "C:\unssz.py", line 38, in main
    print('Decoding key: {}'.format(body_decryption_key.encode('hex')))
AttributeError: 'bytes' object has no attribute 'encode' '

Comment: Installed today Python2.7.9 as recomended and got this message? any idea what is wrong ?   C:\Users\artur\Downloads\SecretZone-master\SecretZone-master>python2 unssz.py C:\Mano.msr
Decoding key: 2a91001c0d0201dea57f29089eee0b2c
No output file specified, giving up...

Comment: how do you run the script ? you must pass the file path as a command line argument when running the script

Comment: Hello , like that >python2 unssz.py Mano.msr   , .msr file is in the same folder where script , I also tried like that >python2 unssz.py C:\Users\artur\Downloads\SecretZone-master\SecretZone-master\Mano.msr

Comment: Or added word 'Something' on the end  C:\Users\artur\Downloads\SecretZone-master\SecretZone-master>python2 unssz.py Mano.msr Something
Decoding key: 2a91001c0d0201dea57f29089eee0b2c
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "unssz.py", line 58, in <module>
    main()
  File "unssz.py", line 44, in main
    decryptor = AES.new(body_decryption_key, AES.MODE_ECB, 16 * '\00')
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\Crypto\Cipher\AES.py", line 232, in new
    raise TypeError("IV is not meaningful for the ECB mode")
TypeError: IV is not meaningful for the ECB mode

Comment: IV is not meaningful for ECB mode is because AES_ECB mode doesn't take an ```IV``` but this error is different from one in the comment above. anyway according to the github page you should run the script something like  ```./patch-msr-files.py input_file output_file``` from the terminal. also check your python interpreter path is the correct one at top of your script. to know your python interpreter path use ```which python2``` command and copy this path instead of already provided one.

Comment: Thank you for path, hopefuly it works,now I have to wait for 300GB data creating, I thought script will edit existing data, THANK YOU !

Comment: Finished, unlocked my old Samsung HDD 'secret' container :) ! Thnx Khaled Gaber for supprot